# To what extent does the popular memory of Bismarck today differ from the historical reality?

Tags: germany, historiography, persona

I'm interested in what discrepancies there may be, between the reality of Bismarck versus the image created in the Collective Memory of Germans. In what ways does the popular impression of Bismark today differ from the actual person, according to historians?

Especially in relation to what comes later in German history: Hitler and the Nazis, Has there been any sign of Bismarck's rough edges, so to speak, being smoothened out, so that Germany can keep at least one important figure clean of the taint of National Socialism?

Comment: What has preliminary research revealed?  Source requests are out of scope, and requests for "What others may know" make an authoritative answer challenging.  You may want to review [help] .

Comment: A request for those voting to close: This is a new user to the site. Please give them a chance to review the comments & update their question before you VtC.

Comment: Welcome to History site. Please, try to edit your question so that it will suppose one concrete answer and not several essays *about* Bismark.

Comment: Request that we constrain the comments to only requests for clarification.  Move discussion to chat.

Comment: I have made an attempt to edit the question to conform to H.SE rules; @Missiej I hope I grasped the gist of your intended question correctly. If not, please feel free to clarify and/or revert the edit.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69814/discussion-on-question-by-missiej-to-what-extent-does-the-popular-memory-of-bism).

Comment: @Semaphore A nobel attempt so I voted to reopen, however, it may still attract opinions.